# Linear Graham scan for convex hull of simple polygon failing

Tags: typescript, algorithm, computational-geometry, convex-hull

Supposedly, the Graham scan algorithm should work to find the convex hull of a simple polygon in linear time, without the nlogn sorting step being necessary (since the vertices f a simple polygon are effectively already sorted). And I have an implementation of the Graham scan which seems to work fine:

```js
function ccw(a: Vertex, b: Vertex, c: Vertex) {
    return (b.y - a.y)*(c.x - a.x) - (b.x - a.x)*(c.y - a.y);
}

// Graham Scan Convex Hull Algorithm
// This is destructive
export function convexHull(points: Vertex[]) {
    const n = points.length;
    if (n <= 3) return points;
    
    // Assume the first point is bottom-left-most
    const p0 = points[0];

    // Sort by angle
    points.sort((a, b) => {
        const c = ccw(p0, a, b);
        return c === 0 ? a.x - b.x : c;
    });

    // Keep points in the result if they "turn left"
    let len = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        let b = points[len-1];
        let c = points[i];
        //if (b.x === c.x && b.y === c.y) { continue; } // identical points are already filtered out
        if (len >= 2) {
            let a = points[len-2];
            while (ccw(a, b, c) >= 0) {
                len--;
                if (len < 2) { break; }
                b = a;
                a = points[len-2];
            }
        }
        points[len++] = c;
    }
    points.length = len;
    return points;
}
```

(Note that polygon representations are already rotated so that point[0] *is* guaranteed to be the bottom-left-most point before this function is ever called.)

Given the test data

```js
[
  { x: 0, y: -1 },
  { x: 0.2886751345948129, y: -0.5 },
  { x: 0.8660254037844387, y: -0.5 },
  { x: 0.5773502691896257, y: 0 },
  { x: 0.8660254037844387, y: 0.5 },
  { x: 0.28867513459481287, y: 0.5 },
  { x: 0, y: 1 },
  { x: -0.28867513459481287, y: 0.5 },
  { x: -0.8660254037844387, y: 0.5 },
  { x: -0.5773502691896257, y: 0 },
  { x: -0.8660254037844387, y: -0.5 },
  { x: -0.2886751345948129, y: -0.5 }
]
```

for a simple radius-1 six-pointed star, this gives the correct result, a bounding hexagon:

```js
[
  { x: 0, y: -1 },
  { x: 0.8660254037844387, y: -0.5 },
  { x: 0.8660254037844387, y: 0.5 },
  { x: 0, y: 1 },
  { x: -0.8660254037844387, y: 0.5 },
  { x: -0.8660254037844387, y: -0.5 }
]
```

However, if I remove the angular sort, even though the input is a simple polygon, it ends up appending an extra interior vertex:

```js
[
  { x: 0, y: -1 },
  { x: 0.8660254037844387, y: -0.5 },
  { x: 0.8660254037844387, y: 0.5 },
  { x: 0, y: 1 },
  { x: -0.8660254037844387, y: 0.5 },
  { x: -0.8660254037844387, y: -0.5 },
  { x: -0.2886751345948129, y: -0.5 }
]
```

Any help debugging this or suggestions for an alternate algorithm to use would be appreciated. I would like to use Lee's algorithm, but I cannot find a good reference implementation or complete psuedocode for it anywhere, and the prose-and-diagrams explanations are proving too hard to follow. I can use Melkman's algorithm, but I don't actually *need* online construction, and I'd prefer to avoid needing to pull in a deque rather than a stack if at all possible.

Comment: @user3386109 That shouldn't matter. The only point of sorting by angle in the Graham scan algorithm is to arrange the vertices into a simple polygon; exactly *which* simple polygon you have is supposed to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know about debugging the version I had, but I sat down with a blank screen and thought real hard about how to re-implement Graham scan from scratch, and I came up with something that actually does work:

```js
// Graham scan. Assumes a simple polygon.
// This is destructive, collecting hull
// vertices in the prefix of the input array.
export function polygonHull(points: Vertex[]) {
    const n = points.length;

    // There can never be fewer than 4 vertices.
    // Assume the first point is bottom-left-most
    const p0 = points[0];

    let top = 1;
    for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        // Duplicate points are pre-filtered
        // if (points[top].x === points[i].x && points[top].y === points[i].y) { continue; }
        points[++top] = points[i];
        while (top >= 2 && ccw(points[top-2], points[top-1], points[top]) >= 0) {
            points[top - 1] = points[top]; // delete internal point
            top--;
        }
    }

    // Fix up the join between the tail and start
    while (ccw(points[top-1], points[top], p0) >= 0) { top--; }

    points.length = top + 1; 
    return points;
}
```

The idea was to stick to the original published version of the algorithm, using a circular doubly-linked list, as possible; and then just make minimal alterations to shift to an array representation, with special handling for the discontinuity at the ends of the array.

Comment: You could just add a copy of the starting point to the end of the list, instead of treating it as a special case.

Comment: @user3386109 that would eliminate the final fix-up loop, but it does nothing to address the fact that the basic algorithm may sometimes require backing up past the starting point, which would push into negative array indices. That's relatively simple to deal with, but it does take some thought to prove you're doing it *right*.

Comment: The basic algorithm can't back up past the starting point because it has an explicit check to prevent that: `while (top >= 2 ...`. The fix-up loop seems to be missing that protection.

Comment: It also seems that you've forgotten to mention another fundamental assumption that you're making, i.e. the list of points form a simple polygon in counterclockwise order. If the points are in clockwise order, the code fails.

Comment: @user3386109 That `top >= 2` check is not part of the original linked-list algorithm; it's something I had to add, along with re-ordering some operations. The fixup loop doesn't need it because it is guaranteed to terminate successfully if the stack gets down to 3 elements--as long as, as you point out, the input is sorted in the correct order! And yes, that is an assumption I forgot to note, but there is linear-time preprocessing that enforces that as well; you just calculate the signed area and then reverse the tail of the list if the sign is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your information is wrong, the Graham scan does not necessarily "works" on a simple polygon. What is true is:

- the Graham scan works on sorted points (star-shaped or monotone polygon) in linear time,
- the Melkman's algorithm works on simple polygons in linear time.

---

This said, for small polygons, sorting is not a big deal. My favorite version is the Monotone Chain version, as it avoids a conversion to polar coordinates.

Large polygons, unless they are pathological, are made of a few already sorted sequences, so sorting with a k-way merge can be advantageous.

If your point set has a large proportion of internal points, preliminary rejection à la Quickhull can be of interest - even leading to linear expected time. Unsure if large simple polygons enjoy this property.